# Passing a List values with a GET in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, list, get

I have the following data-

```
  IList<int> mylist= new List<int>();
    int value=0;
    ViewData["URL"] = "/Services/Getdata/?value="+&value+"&mylist="+mylist;

   // It hits this function   
    public void Getdata(int value,IList<int> mylist)
    {}
```

Now the problem is the list is not being passed over correctly...I am doing a GET here and cannot post the data...so now I know it has to some how pass it like `&mylist[0]=2&mylist[1]=3..so on`...So how  can achieve this...I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819304) but are there other alternatives?

Please help me out here..I can't really use TempData in my case..all I want is to pass an list or array through wire in asp.net mvc? Has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: Are you against using TempData?

Comment: Yea...I cant really use TempData in my case..I am passing this url to .swf which uses it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following function to serialize your list to one string:

```
public string Serialize(System.Collections.Generic.IList<int> list, string paramName) {
    return String.Join("&", list.Select((value, index) => String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}[{1}]={2}", paramName, index, value)));
}
```

Comment: a slight problem i have is I am trying to pass two lists...and somehow it does not do it right when i am doing it...it passes the same list in the both the lists (the second one)...